# Custom Dialog Execution NPE

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-webview, android-dialog

I keep my alerts and dialog's in a seperate class to prevent clutter. In my activity, I have a webView and the HTML document has a button that executes a custom dialog in Android. I'm using the JavaScriptInterface to communicate between the JavaScript functions in the HTML Documents and Android Java methods. This all works fine with my toast messages and other functions between each other except for this custom dialog.

**UPDATE:**

**I did some changes and now at least I get a NPE that I cant follow. I moved the Dialog method to the JavaInterface to make it easier to debug and a few other chages; see comments in the code.**

I don't know what I have wrong. I get no error info in LogCat with this one; just force closes the app...?? Plz look thru my code below.

Thnx for your help!!

LogCat:

> Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
>   threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4024ee20) 
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewCoreThread   java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1745)    at
>   com.andaero.JavaScriptInterface.onCreateDialog(JavaScriptInterface.java:45)
>     at android.app.Activity.onCreateDialog(Activity.java:2758)      at
>   android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:936)      at
>   android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2851)       at
>   android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2810)       at
>   com.andaero.JavaScriptInterface.showDashBoard(JavaScriptInterface.java:32)
>     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)      at
>   android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)       at
>   android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3600(WebViewCore.java:52)       at
>   android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1340)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)      at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)       at
>   android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:723)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)

Alerts And Dialogs Class:

```
public class AlertsAndDialogs extends Activity
{

    public final int CATEGORY_ID = 0;

   . . . 
  //Moved to the JavaScriptInterface Class ----->
   /* protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
      {
      Dialog dialog;
      switch (id)
      {
        case CATEGORY_ID:

        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        Context mContext = this;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.webView));

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setView(layout);
        dialog = builder.create();
        break;

        default:
        dialog = null;
      }
      return dialog;
      }*/

}
```

The JavaScriptInterface Class:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface extends AlertsAndDialogs
{
    public final int CATEGORY_ID = 0;
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c)
    {
    mContext = c;
    }

    . . .

     /** Show the DashBoard from the web page */
    public void showDashBoard()
    {
    showDialog(CATEGORY_ID);
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
    Dialog dialog;
    switch (id)
    {
        case CATEGORY_ID:

        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        //Context mContext = this;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)     mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setView(layout);
        dialog = builder.create();
        break;

        default:
        dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
    }
    . . . 
}
```

In the Main Activity containing the WebView:

```
. . .
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
. . .
```

The HTML Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDashBoardFunction() {
        Android.showDashBoard();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
```

to

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_dialog, null);
```

I find that attaching views to a container rarely (if ever) works, and assuming "layout_root" is something to do with your activity, the Dialog won't be able to find this view anyway.

Comment: Thnx.  I gave that a try but the NPE changed to:  `at android.app.Activity.getVolumeControlStream(Activity.java:4089)
   at android.app.Dialog.setOwnerActivity(Dialog.java:206)
   at android.app.Activity.onPrepareDialog(Activity.java:2767)
   at android.app.Activity.onPrepareDialog(Activity.java:2796)
   at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2859)
   at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2810)
  at com.andaero.JavaScriptInterface.showDashBoard(JavaScriptInterface.java:31)`

Comment: Thnx again for the help, I ended up re-writing the dialog to a more simpler format. see my answer below - And the null was needed for it to work as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Remove from the AlertsAndDialogs Class:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
      {
      Dialog dialog;
      switch (id)
      {
        case CATEGORY_ID:

        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        Context mContext = this;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.webView));

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setView(layout);
        dialog = builder.create();
        break;

        default:
        dialog = null;
      }
      return dialog;
      }
```

and add this:

```
public static void dashBoard(Context mContext)
    {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    Dialog dbDialog;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_dialog, null);

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setView(layout);
    dbDialog = builder.create();
    dbDialog.show();
    }
```

Inside the JavaScriptInterface Class, Replace the call with:

```
public void showDashBoard()
    {
    AlertsAndDialogs.dashBoard(mContext);
    }
```